# Uso do return em python

Tags: python, funções, return

```
def repita():
    x = 2
    while n % x != 0:
    x += 1
repeat()
while n > 1:
    n = n / x #aqui se encontra o primeiro problema, já que "n" não é reconhecido fora da função
    x += 1
    if n % x != 0:#mesmo problema de antes
        repita() #aqui a função se repetiria aumentando o valor do "x"
```

Minha dúvida é sobre como usar o **return** para que "n" e "x" sejam reconhecidos e eu possa trabalhar com eles.

Comment: Extrair? Dividir um pelo outro? Não tá fazendo muito sentido essa pergunta. Explique melhor o que você está fazendo e o que você quer como resultado pra cada entrada.

Comment: Editei a pergunta, minha dúvida ficou mais clara?

Comment: O que eu não estou entendendo é que função é essa. Por que ela existe? O que significa "repita"? Ela parece estar fazendo várias coisas. Por que não simplesmente declara n e x do lado de fora?

Comment: O meu algorítimo ainda está no início, então não sei se vale a pena postá-lo por inteiro apenas para dar sentido para esse trecho, por isso usei como exemplo essa função que não tem muito sentido achando que seria mais fácil de entender a dúvida, mas de qualquer forma vou editar e colocar a função do meu código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso se deve às regras de escopo.

x é criado dentro da função repita, e deixa de existir assim que a função termina.

Pra pegar o valor final de x vc precisa escrever algo como

```
def repita:
    x = 2
    return x
x2 = repita()
```

O return manda o valor de x para fora do escopo da função, e esse valor é atribuído à variável x2.

não é recomendado ter uma variável que vai ser acessada em todo o programa (variável global), mas é possível.

```
x = 2
def repita:
    x = 5
x = x + 5
```

Como a definição inicial está fora da função o valor é alterado dentro e fora da função.